# how do I create a new column based on 3 other columns in my select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a new column in my sql statement that has a flag of a 'Yes' if the MRN and TF_Group are duplicated but the PathID is different (see the link below showing my output)

I have been able to create the column in excel (see the link below and in particular the column titled 'Flag') but just can't think of how to replicate it in sql server. The function that i used to create the 'Flag' column was =if(and(b2=b3,d2=d3,a2<>a3),"Yes","No")

I just don't know how to recreate a similar thing in sql server. Below is the sql code that i have used to extract the data that you can see in the link at the bottom of this post.

Anyone got any ideas?

```
select DISTINCT 
[Pathway ID] PathID,
MRN,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY mrn ORDER BY [Pathway ID]) RK,
[Treatment Function Group] TF_GROUP,
'' [Flag]

from [HRS_RTT].[dbo].[tbl_PMM_IncompletePTL_CG_Snapshot] 
where convert(date,censusdate) between '03-jun-19' and '09-jun-19'
AND MRN IS NOT NULL
AND [Treatment Function Group] IS NOT NULL

order by
MRN,
[Pathway ID]
```

[image]

Comment: I think I see this question before, but take a look at `CASE` expression

Comment: Comparing data between rows is not straightforward in SQL. Keep in mind that SQL works with sets, which are groups of rows that match your criteria. The concept of next or previous row in a set is not really part of SQL, however you may be able to use `lag` or `lead` to do this in SQL Server (see https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/ for example). It may be a better idea to take a different look at how to accomplish your actual goals. What are the actual requirements you're trying to fulfill?

Comment: You may create a function to get the PathID by MRN and RK, and then compare the PathID of RK=1 and RK=2 and set the flag value using CASE statement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to your problem as described. It uses the T-SQL `LEAD` function to compare across rows. Note that I did not include the `DISTINCT` criteria from your original query as it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish with that.

However, as I said in the comment, I don't think this is necessarily how you want to do this. You may want to give some more thought to your requirements and see if you can come up with a better way to fulfill them.

```
select
    PathID,
    MRN,
    TF_Group,
    case
        when MRN = Next_MRN and TF_Group = Next_TF_Group and PathID <> Next_PathID then 'Yes'
        else 'No'
    end as Flag
from (
    select
        [Pathway Id] as PathID,
        MRN,
        [Treatment Function Group] as TF_Group,

        lead([Pathway Id]) over (order by MRN, [Pathway ID]) as Next_PathID,
        lead(MRN) over (order by MRN, [Pathway ID]) as Next_MRN,
        lead([Treatment Function Group])  over (order by MRN, [Pathway ID]) as Next_TF_Group
    from tbl_PMM_IncompletePTL_CG_Snapshot
) x
order by MRN, PathID
```

Comment: Jack, I am currently using sql 2008 which doesn't have the LEAD function. Is there an equivalent function in 2008 or alternative way of doing it without using the function?

Comment: @Shez You may be able to do it with subqueries. You can define a column as a subquery like `Flag as (select case when ... end from ...)`. However, as I mentioned in my earlier comment, you should give some thought to your requirements and try to better define what you are trying to accomplish. That exercise could give you ideas for a better way to approach this as comparing between rows is not well supported in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments:

```
select DISTINCT 
[Pathway ID] PathID,
MRN,
CASE WHEN MRN = MRN AND [Treatment Function Group] = [Treatment Function Group] AND [Pathway ID] <> [Pathway ID] THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END [Flag]
from [HRS_RTT].[dbo].[tbl_PMM_IncompletePTL_CG_Snapshot] 
where convert(date,censusdate) between '03-jun-19' and '09-jun-19'
AND MRN IS NOT NULL
AND [Treatment Function Group] IS NOT NULL

order by
MRN,
[Pathway ID]
```

Comment: I think you might want to be more specific with your columns. For example, `MRN = MRN` is referring to the same column on both sides so will always match.